# Bluetooth connection, change some variable in python from android (java)

Tags: android, python, bluetooth

I would like to change some value of variable in python by a simple press a button on my application between my smartphone and my raspberry PI 3.

I use this java code to get value from my raspberry PI by bluetooth :

```
private void startThreadConnected(BluetoothSocket socket){
        myThreadConnected = new ThreadConnected(socket);
        myThreadConnected.start();
    }
    /*
    ThreadConnectBTdevice:
    Background Thread to handle BlueTooth connecting
    */


    private class ThreadConnectBTdevice extends Thread {

        private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;
        private final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
        Dialog dialog;

        private ThreadConnectBTdevice(BluetoothDevice device, Dialog dialog) {
            this.dialog = dialog;
            bluetoothDevice = device;
            connexion.setText("Déconnexion");

            try {
                bluetoothSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connexion établi !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean success = false;
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.connect();
                success = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                final String eMessage = e.getMessage();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "something wrong bluetoothSocket.connect(): \n" + eMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                try {
                    bluetoothSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(success){
                //connect successful
          /*      final String msgconnected = "connect successful:\n"
                        + "BluetoothSocket: " + bluetoothSocket + "\n"
                        + "BluetoothDevice: " + bluetoothDevice;*/

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                startThreadConnected(bluetoothSocket);

            }else{
                //fail
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Déconnexion !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

private class ThreadConnected extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket connectedBluetoothSocket;
    private final InputStream connectedInputStream;
    private final OutputStream connectedOutputStream;

    boolean running;

    public ThreadConnected(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        connectedBluetoothSocket = socket;
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        running = true;
        try {
            in = socket.getInputStream();
            out = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connectedInputStream = in;
        connectedOutputStream = out;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000]; // buffer 
        final GraphView graph=(GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);

        while (running) {
            try {
                final int bytes;
                bytes=connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
                final String strReceived = new String(buffer,0, bytes); 

                final String strByteCnt = String.valueOf(bytes) + " bytes received.\n";
                final String terminale=new String(buffer,0,bytes);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                        myThreadConnected.write(data like you want )

                    }});

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                cancel();

                final String msgConnectionLost = "Connection lost:\n" + e.getMessage();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }});
            }
        }
    }
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            connectedOutputStream.write(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void cancel() {
        running = false;
        try {
            connectedBluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And this code in python to send data :

```
from bluetooth import*

a=5

#Bluetooth connection
server_sock=BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port=server_sock.getsockname()[1]
uuid="94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"
client_sock,client_info=server_sock.accept()
client_sock.send(a)

try
  data=client_sock.recv(1024)
  if len(data)==0: break
  data2=float(data)
  a=data2
  print ("received [%f]" %a)
except IOError:
  pass
```

Now I want from the java code to change the value of my variable in python. How can I process with the same logic ?

Illustration : [android to python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EE8m.png)

link usefull : http://android-er.blogspot.fr/2015/11/android-bluetooth-terminal.html

Thanks !

Comment: You must make receive what you send from python in android side. store it on some new variable in Android and then try to send back it to python side

Comment: yeah thanks ! I finally found. It was very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this simply with:

```
try
     data=client_sock.recv(1024)
     if len(data)==0: break
     data2=float(data)
     a=data2
except IOError:
      pass
```